# Can`t run emulator in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I am trying to run emulator in android studio but I got error: filelock_lock: error not already exists
Running with comand:  ./emulator -avd emulator_name -netspeed full -netdelay none
Running from android studio show the same result
I have already instal HAXM, trying different fixes and I don`t  know what is the problem

Console error:
[image: console error]

Comment: Have you tried creating a new emulator?

Comment: Yes, but getting the same

Comment: Probably some process is already using it. Can you try restarting the system to release all the file locks?

Comment: Yes, I have restarted system, but same. I think, maybe some other program occupied resource every time when system is starting

Comment: Have you enable virtualization in bios settings ? also use task manager to check occupied resources in the memory section